# Pdf file not opening after attaching files using PyPDF2

Tags: pdf, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 to attach files to a .pdf. It seems files have to be opened in binary mode. However after adding the files, Adobe cannot open the file. It says "root object is missing or invalid". Do we have to decode the file back? Could you please suggest a way?

```
import PyPDF2 
fr = PyPDF2.PdfReader(open('Closeout.pdf', 'rb')) 
fw = PyPDF2.PdfWriter() 
fw.append_pages_from_reader(fr) 
fw.add_attachment('input0_file.pdf','input0.pdf'.encode()) 
with open('Blankpdf.pdf', 'wb') as output: 
    fw.write(output)
```

Referring to the below thread as well since the same issue was faced.

[How to attach mulitple files in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085308/how-to-attach-mulitple-files-in-pdf#comment104635595_59085770)

I tried PyPDF2. And also the solution mentioned in below thread.

[How to attach mulitple files in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085308/how-to-attach-mulitple-files-in-pdf#comment104635595_59085770)

However the final pdf files end up throwing the below error.
Reference: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLa5N.jpg)

Updated code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter 
fr = PdfReader('Closeout.pdf', 'rb') 
fw = PdfWriter() 
fw.append_pages_from_reader(fr) 
with open('input0.pdf', 'rb') as file: 
    filedata = file.read() 
fw.add_attachment('input0.pdf', filedata) 
with open('Blankpdf.pdf', 'wb') as output: 
    fw.write(output) 
fw.close()
```

Error Output:
[Post update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k5BX.png)

Update - 08-March-2023

The same issue

'root object is missing or invalid' / 'There was an error opening this document. There was a problem reading this document(14). Expected a dict object.'

are reoccurring and this time it has occurred for a different set of files.

code:

```py
import PyPDF2 as pdf2
output = pdf2.PdfWriter()

with open ("test.pdf", "rb") as f:
    input_pdf = pdf2.PdfReader(f)
    output.append_pages_from_reader(input_pdf)

with open("test2.pdf", "rb") as pdfFile:
    output.add_attachment("test2.pdf", pdfFile.read())

with open ("test3.pdf", "ab") as f:
    output.write(f)
```

Could you please try this code and let me know what am I doing wrong? The pdfs contain only text. test1.pdf contains the text 'test1' whereas test2.pdf contains the text 'test2'.

This is the message I get when opening the output file 'test3.pdf'.

[image: Error when opening output file 'test3.pdf']
[image: Details on 'ctrl+Ok']

Comment: Helping you would be much easier, if you showed what you are actually doing. For instance by including the code you are using ...

Comment: Before you start attaching an image/screenshot of your code: Please post code as text and not as image ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Appreciate your help. The pdf files used are normal pdf files.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/PdfWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfWriter.add_attachment) the second parameter of `add_attachment` has to be the file data. You are just passing a filename. Ie you have to read the file from your disk first ... See also the anwer you already linked. They are reading each of the files to be attached from the disk first, and then pass the data to `add_attachment`

Comment: I see. Thanks..I have updated the code as above. But I get the new error (14) as shown above.

Comment: When I ctrl+click on OK in the error message I get the detail as 'Expected a dict object'

Comment: If you fixed it, consider writing an answer with the pitfalls you discovered / how to deal with them

Comment: @derpirscher  Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
fw.append_pages_from_reader(fr)
```

try

```
fw.clone_document_from_reader(fr)
```

Also the mode for writing the output file must be "wb" and not "ab" (there's a typo in your code).

This will get read of the error opening your document.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the latest version of the package, pypdf (instead of PyPDF2). I had the same problem and it was fixed up upgrading the dependency. Now, using pypdf 3.9.1, the error message has gone.

---

See my more complete answer to much the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440685/18289827)